# Всплывающие сообщения по типу ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Здравствуйте!

Есть технология, которая показывает уведомления на сайте, если пришло входящее сообщение, например, как во ВКонтакте или на Яндекс.Почте. В моём понимании AJAX работает примерно по такому же принципу с той разницей, что AJAX отправляет запрос к серверу без перезагрузки сообщения. В данном случае, всё инициализируется клиентом.

А как же тогда появляются сообщения на сайте уже от сервера? Это же не AJAX. Как называется эта технология?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Push-уведомления, читай здесь: https://pushall.ru/blog/whatispushnotifications

Answer (score 0):

В Wiki всегда найдется ответ:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket

Answer (score 0):

Как тебе сказали websoket, на php это обычно поднимается демон или также есть способ использовать long poll, когда запрос ждет обновления. И как вариант можно сделать отдельную базу в которую идут все уведомления, у каждого уведомления будет отдельный id, который определяет какую функцию запустить